# Restoring Projects from Eclipse IDE when all projects are gone

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ide, m2eclipse

I was in a hurry to shutdown my laptop, so I canceled the eclipse, and after that when saving workspace tab pops up I mistakenly closed that too.
So after opening my eclipse again the whole projects are gone.The Project Explorer is empty.
Can anyone helpme out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to set that workspace aside, create a new workspace, and import your old workspace's existing projects into the new workspace.

Comment: Thanks man, Your answer gave me new approach though.In File their's a option of Open  Projects from File System, from there I managed to give it's Directory.